# Reducing OCR time using blink ID

Tags: android, performance, ocr

We have been using blink id as the OCR tool in android. But when there is ambient light , the third party library takes too long to scan because the documents are laminated. Does anybody know a way to reduce scanning time by probably locking the focus of the camera.

Answer (score 2):

[BlinkID](https://github.com/BlinkID/blinkid-android) can use one or more recognisers to perform ID scanning. The scanning time depends on number of currently active recognisers (the more are active, the longer the scanning time is). Which ID are you trying to scan?

BlinkID currently supports [US Driver License barcodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Driver%27s_license_in_the_United_States) (back side), [UK Driver Licence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Driving_licence_in_the_United_Kingdom) (front side), [German Driver Licence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Driving_licence_in_Germany) (front side), [Malaysian MyKad ID Card](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malaysian_identity_card) (front side) and generic [Machine Readable Travel Document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine-readable_passport) (passports and ID cards containing Machine Readable Zone).

If you are simply trying to perform general purpose OCR of camera frame with [BlinkID segment scan recogniser](https://github.com/BlinkID/blinkid-android#blinkOCR) (which is also available in [BlinkOCR](https://github.com/BlinkOCR/blinkocr-android)), then you can tweak OCR settings if you use [Raw parser](https://blinkid.github.io/blinkid-android/com/microblink/recognizers/blinkocr/parser/generic/RawParserSettings.html): you can use method [setOcrEngineOptions](https://blinkid.github.io/blinkid-android/com/microblink/recognizers/blinkocr/parser/generic/RawParserSettings.html#setOcrEngineOptions-com.microblink.recognizers.blinkocr.engine.BlinkOCREngineOptions-) to set generic OCR engine options which define which [fonts and characters are allowed](https://blinkid.github.io/blinkid-android/com/microblink/recognizers/blinkocr/engine/BlinkOCREngineOptions.html#addCharToWhitelist-char-com.microblink.results.ocr.OcrFont-), [how much text is expected](https://blinkid.github.io/blinkid-android/com/microblink/recognizers/blinkocr/engine/BlinkOCREngineOptions.html#setMaximumCharsExpected-int-), what are [minimum](https://blinkid.github.io/blinkid-android/com/microblink/recognizers/blinkocr/engine/BlinkOCREngineOptions.html#setMinimumLineHeight-int-) and [maximum](https://blinkid.github.io/blinkid-android/com/microblink/recognizers/blinkocr/engine/BlinkOCREngineOptions.html#setMaximumLineHeight-int-) height of text lines and [much more](https://blinkid.github.io/blinkid-android/com/microblink/recognizers/blinkocr/engine/BlinkOCREngineOptions.html).

BlinkID uses automatic camera management and tries to keep image as sharp as possible on given device to get the best possible scan result. However, [on some android devices the camera driver behaves differently when used within native camera app and via Android Camera API](http://developer.samsung.com/forum/board/thread/view.do?boardName=SDK&messageId=289824&startId=zzzzz~&searchType=ALL&searchText=autofocus). Issues like these are specific to specific devices or device vendors and BlinkID cannot always have workarounds for it.

And last, but not least: if you are trying to scan a document which has a glare due to receiving direct light, please try scanning under more evenly lighted conditions - at the moment BlinkID cannot remove glare effect from laminated documents.

Disclaimer: I work for [MicroBlink](https://microblink.com/), the company behind [BlinkID](https://microblink.com/blinkid).

Comment: We are using recognizer view and Samsung phones. The ambient light thing we are not able to help that is why finding api to reduce scanning time by other parameters. Is there a way camera focus can be locked.  As we do not need to refocus after every scan and this can reduce login time for us.

Comment: Automatic camera management locks the focus and does not release it after it has been found until device is moved. BlinkID does not offer API to lock the focus of internal camera management, however you can use our [DirectAPI demo](https://github.com/BlinkID/blinkid-android/tree/master/BlinkIDDemo/BlinkIDDirectApiDemo) as a basis for custom camera management and then you can implement camera focus as you wish.

Comment: DirectAPI demo talks about managing the complete camera, start click etc.  Is there a way to get the camera object in camera listener call back or another call bak so that I can call lock autofocus in onCameraPreviewStopped() e.g.  Basically the idea is to scan all the images with the same focus settings

Comment: No, there are no way to do that. You can either use complete camera management on your own (the manual way), or you can use BlinkID's automatic camera management. There is no "semi-automatic" camera management support.

Comment: The problem with that is that BlinkID internally does not always use camera object per se. On some devices it attempts to use Camera2 API and fallbacks to Camera1 API on older devices. Because of this complexity and the big difference between the camera APIs, it is not possible to expose any of the internal camera related objects to 3rd party. If you need special camera behaviour, I recommend managing the camera on your own, as described in DirectAPI demo.

Comment: @DoDo what OCR technology do you use in MicroBlink. Tesseract, maybe?

Comment: @ZhivkoKabaivanov, we have our own OCR technology. For more information about our technology and licensing opportunities, please take a look at [our site](https://microblink.com/en/technology).

Comment: It would be nicer if you provide the link to number of supported countries (with supported documents) list.

Comment: @MuhammadHannan, please contact support@microblink.com for information about supported countries and supported documents.

Comment: @DoDo: how much for the license ?

Comment: @HaiHw, please contact [our sales team](https://microblink.com/contact-us) about pricing.